# Cronjob Homestead not working

Tags: ssh, cron, command, schedule, homestead

I've created a command to send automatic emails. When I do `homestead ssh` and I run `php artisan emails.send` an email arrives in my mailtrap.io account.

I've added this code to the kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

I've put it at a 5 minute interval, just to make it easier to quickly test it.
I've ssh'd into Homestead and performed

```
php /home/vagrant/Code/soeptime/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null    2>&1
```

then I `exit` homestead and I did `homestead provision`

However, there is nothing in the logs and I still haven't received an email, homestead is now running for more then 15 minutes.

Comment: Today I restarted my homestead and I ran 'php artisan sschedule:run' than cli executed this: 'Running scheduled command: /usr/bin/php5 artisan emails.send > /dev/null 2>&1 &' and I got an email in my mailtrap. What does this mean? It isn't happening automatically? I can only run this once, if I try like 15 minutes later it says 'No scheduled commands are ready to run.'

Comment: so, is it already time for soup? :-)

Answer (score 12):

You need to manually edit crontab:

First:

```
 crontab -e
```

and then add

```
* * * * * php /home/vagrant/Code/soeptime/artisan schedule:run
```

Comment: Upvoting for "/home/vagrant/" at the start of the path, this seems to be missing from a lot of articles

Answer (score 8):

### From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#configuring-cron-schedules):

> Laravel provides a convenient way to schedule Cron jobs by scheduling
>   a single `schedule:run` Artisan command to be run every minute. The
>   `schedule:run` command will examine the job schedule defined in your
>   `App\Console\Kernel` class to determine which jobs should be run.
>
> If you would like the `schedule:run` command to be run for a Homestead
>   site, you may set the `schedule` option to `true` when defining the site:

```
sites:
   - map: homestead.test
     to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public
     schedule: true
```

> The Cron job for the site will be defined in the `/etc/cron.d` folder of the virtual machine.